# to checked whether one of the radio button is checked or not from a particular radio group

Tags: php, html, input, radio-button, checked

All the inputs have the same name as `option<?=$x?>` for each loop but always the input with `type=hidden` of the last line overrides all of them although one of the radio buttons with same name `option<?=$x?>` is selected

Is there anyway so that I can check whether anyone out of four radios of above is chosen or not, if not then I have to pass the last input instead of them

```
<input type="radio" name="option<?=$x?>" value="<?=$chioce[0].';'.$data['id'].';'.$data['subject']?>" ><?=$chioce[0]?>
<input type="radio" name="option<?=$x?>" value="<?=$chioce[1].';'.$data['id'].';'.$data['subject']?>" ><?=$chioce[1]?>
<input type="radio" name="option<?=$x?>" value="<?=$chioce[2].';'.$data['id'].';'.$data['subject']?>" ><?=$chioce[2]?>
<input type="radio" name="option<?=$x?>" value="<?=$chioce[3].';'.$data['id'].';'.$data['subject']?>" ><?=$chioce[3]?>

<input type="hidden" name="option<?=$x?>" value="null;<?=$data['id'].';'.$data['subject']?>">
```

Comment: change the hidden field name

Comment: if i change the hidden field name then i wouldn't get the value such as id and question which  will be required under same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
<input type="radio" name="option[<?=$x?>]['radio']" value="<?=$chioce[0].';'.$data['id'].';'.$data['subject']?>" ><?=$chioce[0]?>
<input type="radio" name="option[<?=$x?>]['radio']" value="<?=$chioce[1].';'.$data['id'].';'.$data['subject']?>" ><?=$chioce[1]?>
<input type="radio" name="option[<?=$x?>]['radio']" value="<?=$chioce[2].';'.$data['id'].';'.$data['subject']?>" ><?=$chioce[2]?>
<input type="radio" name="option[<?=$x?>]['radio']" value="<?=$chioce[3].';'.$data['id'].';'.$data['subject']?>" ><?=$chioce[3]?>

<input type="hidden" name="option[<?=$x?>]['hidden']" value="null;<?=$data['id'].';'.$data['subject']?>">`
```

Now when you post you will get `option` array

```
$options = $_POST['option'];
$radioValue = $options[$x]['radio'];
$hiddenValue = $options[$x]['hidden'];
```

You can read value like this

```
$optionValue = isset($options[$x]['radio']) ? $options[$x]['radio'] : $options[$x]['hidden'];
```

Hope it may help you

Comment: sorry but i need that hidden value if and only if none of the radio button is selected as it is giving us the information that chioce is null...value="null;<?=$data['id'].';'.$data['subject']?>"

Comment: thats fine, if you have not selected radio button then it will have `$hiddenValue = $options[1][$x];` only. try it once

Comment: updated answer with associative array. check it once